# What would cause an uploaded image via PHP display in a browser but not in Windows Explorer?

Tags: php

This PHP script uploads a file which is an image, when the image has been uploaded to the directory it is viewable in the browser, but when I navigate to the image in Windows Explorer I can not view it. What would be the cause of this and why is image behaving in this manner?

```
$valid_formats = array("jpg", "png", "gif", "bmp","jpeg");
if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
$name = $_FILES['photoimg']['name'];
$size = $_FILES['photoimg']['size'];
if(strlen($name)) {
    list($txt, $ext) = explode(".", $name);
    if(in_array($ext,$valid_formats)) {
        if($size<(1024*1024)) {
            $actual_image_name = time().".".$ext;
            $tmp = $_FILES['photoimg']['tmp_name'];
//This is where the image upload is executed.
            if(move_uploaded_file($tmp, $path.$actual_image_name)) {
                chmod($path.$actual_image_name, 0777);
                    echo "<img src='".$path.$actual_image_name."' class='preview' width='306px'>";
            }
            else {
                echo "failed";
            }
        }
        else {
            echo "Image file size max 1 MB";
        }
    }
    else {
        echo "Invalid file format..";
    }
}
else {
    echo "Please select image..!";
    exit;
}
}
?>
```

Comment: The problem is that you're using Windows, and not being able to view the image in Explorer is not a PHP issue/question.

Comment: But I am able to view the Image before I upload it via PHP, so basic logic states that if it's viewable before upload but not after it's been uploaded via a PHP script then somehow the PHP script is altering some meta data which makes it a valid PHP question.

Comment: hints: you're not checking at all if the upload succeeded, and just blindly proceed as if it has. you're also trusting the uploader to not lie to you about the file's type.

Comment: Check the file size. Is the uploaded file bigger or smaller than before? What is the server setup? I remember trying to use PHP as an Apache 2 filter before and that was sort of buggy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are writing php in windows interface then I don't think you need to chmod, chmod is only for Linux base. In the meantime help yourself with [this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/tutorials/os-php-graphic/section10.html).

Comment: Please stop calling people "kid". It is insulting, whether or not you mean it to be.

Comment: i didnot know a kid is insulting... i take your advice brother @meagar